# Moved sync issues folder in deleted items as subfolder

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office-365

I have a Office 365 user who has managed to move his sync issue folder to the deleted items.

Now the user is not able to use empty folder anymore because of the subfolder system folder sync issues folder in the deleted items.

Is there any know way to restore the sync issues folder to it's orginal hierarchy level.
I tried `outlook /resetfolders` without any effect.

Comment: Have you tried moving the deleted folder from the Deleted Items folder back into the mailbox hierarchy?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes I tried this but the user is not allowed to do this. The commands are shown grayed.

Comment: If you're able to access her mailbox as an administrative user you might try it from there.

Comment: @joeqwerty My user is in the TenantAdmins Group. So I should have the necessary rights

Comment: Even the MSFT Sr. Support Escalation Engineer has no idea how this could happen. Stay tuned for more updates

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen that happen before myself.  Usually I bite the bullet and just go with new profiles and re-sync the mail.  It's not worth the effort to fix it.